# Create binary tree from inorder and post order traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

I was trying to familarize with the question of creating a tree given inorder and postorder traversal. I wrote the following code, but some thing is going wrong which i was unable to find out. Can someone help me on this?

Sample i/p :

int in[] = {4,10,3,1,7,11,8,2};
        int post[] = {4,1,3,10,11,8,2,7};

```
public static TreeNode buildInorderPostorder( int post[], int n, int offset,Map<Integer,Integer> indexMap,int size) {     
      if (size <= 0) return null;
      int rootVal = post[n-1];
      int i = (indexMap.get(rootVal) - offset);
      TreeNode root = new TreeNode(rootVal);
      root.setLeft(buildInorderPostorder( post, i, offset,indexMap,i-offset));
      root.setRight(buildInorderPostorder(post, n-1, offset+i,indexMap,n-1-i));
      return root;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the inorder traversal be in order?

Comment: its not a binary search tree

Comment: _______7______
       /              \
    __10__          ___2
   /      \        /
   4       3      _8
            \    /
             1  11

Answer (score 0):

`root.setRight` seems to be wrong.offset shouldn't be `offset+i`, it should be `offset+i+1`:

```
root.setRight(buildInorderPostorder(post, n-1, offset+i+1,indexMap,n-1-i));
```

Comment: I tried this, but still not working .public static TreeNode buildInorderPostorder( int post[], int n, int offset,Map<Integer,Integer> indexMap,int size) {   
    if (size <= 0) return null;
    int rootVal = post[n-1];
    int i = (indexMap.get(rootVal) - offset);
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(rootVal);
    root.setLeft(buildInorderPostorder( post, i, offset,indexMap,i-offset));
    root.setRight(buildInorderPostorder(post, n-1, offset+i+1,indexMap,n-1-i));
    return root;
  }

Comment: I am checking further error.Can you please post the entire program at ideone http://ideone.com/  and send us the link?